# Creating and populating temp table in different commands

Tags: c#, sql-server

Im running into an issue where I create a temp table `#muMapping` in one `SqlCommand`, and populate it with another `SqlCommand`. The second command with throw an exception on `cmd.ExecutNonQuery()` with the message:

```
Invalid object name '#muMapping'.
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
```

Both commands use the same `SqlConnection`, and I begin and specify the transaction to be used so that `SqlCommand` will not implicitly begin and commit a transaction.

Code:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    await OpenConnection(conn);
    var trans = conn.BeginTransaction();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE #muMapping ( mu_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, facility NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, team NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL );";
        cmd.Transaction = trans;

        await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }

    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO #muMapping VALUES (@mu, @facility, @team);";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@mu", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@facility", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@team", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        cmd.Transaction = trans;

        cmd.Prepare();

        foreach (var mu in loadData)
        {
            try
            {
                cmd.Parameters[0].Value = mu.Mu;
                cmd.Parameters[1].Value = mu.Facility;
                cmd.Parameters[2].Value = mu.Team;
                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(); //Error thrown here
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
    //Other statements
}
```

From what I can see, the `#muMapping` table should be visible from that second command.

Comment: You have one cmd.Transaction = trans and one cmd.Transaction = transaction.  Is that a transcription error or is it actually in your code?

Comment: @antlersoft It was a transcription error and is now fixed

Comment: What are you trying to do?  If you are just trying to batch load data you might look at [table valued parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 4):

from [Create Table](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)

> You can create local and global temporary tables. Local temporary
>   tables are visible only in the current session, and global temporary
>   tables are visible to all sessions. Temporary tables cannot be
>   partitioned.

So, create a global temporary table (##table_name)

**UPDATE**

Ignore my previous statement, I ran your code (with very few modifications) agains sql server 2014 and it executed just fine!

```
public static void Bar()
    {

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Server=.;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync();
                var trans = conn.BeginTransaction();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText =
                        "CREATE TABLE #muMapping ( mu_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, facility NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, team NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL );";
                    cmd.Transaction = trans;

                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }

                using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO #muMapping VALUES (@mu, @facility, @team);";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@mu", SqlDbType.Int);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@facility", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@team", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
                    cmd.Transaction = trans;

                    cmd.Prepare();


                    foreach (var i in new[] {1, 2, 3})
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters[0].Value = i;
                            cmd.Parameters[1].Value = "f";
                            cmd.Parameters[2].Value = "t";
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Error thrown here
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                            throw;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }).Wait();

        //Other statements
    }
```

Looks like you may have a syntax error:
[Statement(s) Could Not Be Prepared. (SQL Error 37000)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/966722)

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
{
cn.Open();


SqlTransaction transaction = cn.BeginTransaction();


SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("create table #temp (colX int, colY int)", cn, 
transaction);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


cmd = new SqlCommand("insert #temp values (10, 200)", cn, transaction);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from #temp", cn, transaction);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());


transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//s.tk/meta/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!